# SSO for Rails 4 applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, single-sign-on, rack, cas

Let me explain what i am trying to achieve. I have two applications say **App1** & **App2**. When i am log into either **App1** or **App2** i can able to use other App.

For these what i have done is followed [CASino](http://casino.rbcas.com/) i made **App1** was server and for **App2** which acts as client followed  [Rack-cas](https://github.com/biola/rack-cas) github. According to **Rack-cas** documentation if i run the client it need to point **CASino** server app. But it's not pointing may be i missed something  If any one had already succeed in these share their ideas, so that i can achieve.Here is the code i tried in client:

rack-cas-client: config/application.rb:

> ```
> config.rack_cas.server_url = 'http://localhost:3001/'
> require 'rack-cas/session_store/active_record'
> config.rack_cas.session_store = RackCAS::ActiveRecordStore
> config.rack_cas.extra_attributes_filter = %w(email fullname)
> config.rack_cas.verify_ssl_cert = false
> config.rack_cas.renew = true
> ```

Comment: show some code, without a code its hard to debug.. Show us what you have done so far, and then someone might catch your issue. Without a code, all we can say is  `yes , you may be missing something` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was working as expected. I have to add server_url to development.rb